# Referecing numerical column names as variables in R

Tags: r

I have a dataframe where columns are numneri

```
asd <- data.frame(`2021`=rnorm(3), `2`=head(letters,3), check.names=FALSE)
```

But when I reference the columns names as variable, it is returning error

```
 x = 2021
asd[x]
Error in `[.data.frame`(asd, x) : undefined columns selected
```

Expected output

```
x = 2021
asd[x]
        2021 
1  1.5570860
2 -0.8807877
3 -0.7627930
```

Comment: It's saved as a string `asd["2021"]`.

Comment: So how do I reference it via variables. Because you have hard coded it as 2021. Can we not pass this to a variable and then cal it?

Answer (score 4):

Reference it as a string:

```
x = "2021"
asd[,x]
[1] -0.2317928 -0.1895905  1.2514369
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `deparse`

```
asd[,deparse(x)]
[1]  1.3445921 -0.3509493  0.5028844
asd[deparse(x)]
        2021
1  1.3445921
2 -0.3509493
3  0.5028844
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more detail: numbers without quotes are not syntactically valid because they are parsed as numbers, so you will not be able to refer to them as column names without including quotes.

You can force R to interpret a number as a column name by
asd$`2021`

```
> asd$`2021`
[1] -0.634175 -1.612425  1.164135
```

Generally, you can protect yourself against syntactically invalid column names by

```
#(in base R)
names(asd) <- make.names(names(asd))
names(asd)
[1] "X2021" "X2"

#(or in tidyverse)
asd <- as_tibble(asd, .name_repair="universal")
New names:
* `2021` -> ...2021
* `2` -> ...2
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  ...2021 ...2
    <dbl> <chr>
1  -0.634 a
2  -1.61  b
3   1.16  c
```

Answer (score 1):

If the value is numeric, just convert to character with `as.character` - column/row names attributes are all `character` values

```
asd[as.character(x)]
        2021
1 -0.4438473
2 -0.8904154
3 -0.9319593
```